# I want to write code outside a loop in python without stopping the loop

Tags: python

```
import keyboard
while True:
  if keyboard.is_pressed('w'):
    with open('test.py', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     data[1] = ("movement = Forward" + '\n')
    with open('test.py', 'w') as f:
     f.writelines(data)
  elif keyboard.is_pressed('s'):
    with open('test.py', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     data[1] = ("movement = Backward" + '\n')
    with open('test.py', 'w') as f:
     f.writelines(data)
  elif keyboard.is_pressed('d'):
    with open('test.py', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     data[1] = ("movement = Right" + '\n')
    with open('test.py', 'w') as f:
     f.writelines(data)
  elif keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
    with open('test.py', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     data[1] = ("movement = Left" + '\n')
    with open('test.py', 'w') as f:
     f.writelines(data)
exec(open('test.py').read())
```

the last like of code `exec(open('test.py').read())`
is unreachable code i want it to work but i dont want it to be in the loop and i dont want to break/stop the loop

Comment: why not run that statement before the loop starts?

Comment: Or add some code at the bottom of the loop which runs that statement only on the first loop iteration.

Comment: You should read about the security problems with using `exec`, especially if you're reading a n external file and executing it

Comment: It's unreachable because the loop never ends.  You are always replacing the second line of the file.  Were you trying to build up a set of lines?  Why don't you just execute those lines in line?